# Display Hierarchical Data with Feed Time in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

We are working on building End to End Flow dashboard for different Business Delivery Flows. One example would be, Making data available for users to sign off.

To delivery this data for users to sign off, there can be many systems involved including feed arrival, feed processing, calculations on data etc. These details are being captured at 3 Hierarchical level.

- Main Flow

  - Sub Flows

    - Stages

For each of these levels, start and end times are captured which will help generate duration as well.

We want to capture these data and show real time on Grafana to display End To End Flow tracking.

I have been trying to search but most examples are around capturing the metrics which are number / decimals but not Time. Apologies if it's very basic but could someone help how this data can be captured and then shown on Grafana for real time monitoring of the flows?

Very new to Grafana, have tried searching but mostly found the numerical metric examples only but not the time related.

**Example Data:**
[Main Flow Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCrzF.png)

[Sub Flow Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZFQD.png)

[Stage Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK0jK.png)